# How can I get the screen resolution in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen resolution java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/screen-resolution-java)

Hi,

How can I get screen resolution in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/screen-resolution-java

Answer (score 19):

You can use AWT Toolkit,

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

or better java2d, which supports multi monitor setups:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Comment: from where the Dimension class comes in? @mdma ?

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the screen resolution (screen size) using the Toolkit class. This method call returns the screen resolution in pixels, and stores the results in a Dimension object, as shown here:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

You can then get the screen width and height as int's by directly accessing the width and height fields of the Dimension class, like this:

```
screenHeight = screenSize.height;
screenWidth = screenSize.width;
```

[check this](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/java-swing-faq-how-determine-screen-size-resolution)

[another method](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/Tricks/ScreenRes/)

Answer (score 2):

By using [java.awt.Toolkit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29)'s `getScreenSize()` method.