# Get screens configuration in Java

Tags: java, configuration, screen, awt

I am trying to find a way to know what kind of screen configuration the User is using.

For example, He could be having 2 screens positioned horizontally, or 2 vertically, or simply 1 or even 2 screen horizontally and 2 vertically (2x2).

Is there a way to catch that?

So far, I managed to get the amount of screens the User has.

```
int devices = g.getScreenDevices().length;
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/screen-resolution-java) might help you

Comment: It doesn't :(. I need to find their configuration. Like the one you can see in the Control Panel of Windows. [Screen 1 right, Screen 2 left]

Comment: Silly me, you already have them. doesn't `g.getScreenDevices` return an array you can iterate through?

Comment: *"I am trying to find a way to know what kind of screen configuration the User is using."*  There is always 'ask them'.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the different screens there. I suppose your `g` field is the local environment obtained through `GraphicsEnvironment#getLocalGraphicsEnvironment`. Then, by doing `g.getScreenDevices` you already have an array with the current screens (BTW, the line of code you posted shouldn't compile).

So, to access each scren you can do this:

```
GraphicsDevice[] devices = g.getScreenDevices();

for(GraphicsDevice currentDevice : devices) {
    DisplayMode deviceDisplayMode = currentDevice.getDisplayMode();
    //From here onwards, use deviceDisplayMode.getWidth() and
    //deviceDisplayMode.getHeight()
}
```

Comment: The only way it could be useful would that it returns a matrix. I need to know that device[1] is the left one and so on.