# GUI scaling for different screen resolutions and sizes

Tags: java, user-interface, scaling

As a beginner programmer I have been making very simple programs and dabbling in GUIs using Java. It occurred to me the other day that everything I have made is done and tested on the same resolution screen so I tried changing my resolution and the GUIs were just awful, half of them did not even fit all the components on to the screen.

I assume using scaling variables for the components is the solution but what do the pros typically use when scaling their apps?  I was thinking possibly getting the screen resolution/size ( I can't remember the tool for it but I've definitely seen it ) then scaling based on those results but perhaps there is a more simple technique that I haven't considered.

Comment: Layout managers and scroll panes.  You also need consider the density of the content.  More than about 5-10 items on the screen and your user starts to go cross eyed (this is an opinion, so might find more or less items more comfortable).  You might consider using something like `JTabbedPane` to reduce the clutter.  `JSplitPane` is another option

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to decide on a minimum supported screen resolution and design for that, using something like `setPreferredSize(width, height)` to size your top-level windows. If the user has a larger-resolution screen, they can resize your application; like MadProgrammer implied, your layout manager should be set up to resize gracefully.

If you really want to be responsive, you can isolate the code that sets up your layout manager in a method that takes the current screen resolution (that you can get using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680236/421784)) and arrange components differently based on, say, the width of the screen.