# How to get the width and height of current monitor in java

Tags: java, swing, screen-size, multiple-monitors

how to get width and height of screen of current monitor in multimonitor scenarios in java.

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

This piece of code gives the width and height of same monitor even if I run in other monitor.

How do you get the width and height of current monitor. Please help.

Comment: Here is your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java

Comment: Hi MuGiK, thanks.. I need the resolution of current monitor in use. It gives me default device and not current device I believe. Please help me identifying the size of current monitor in use and not default monitor. GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
GraphicsDevice gd[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
```

Then you'll have all your monitor in the array.

Now get width and height:

```
int width = gd[n].getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd[n].getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Comment: how do u identify current monitor .. MuGik.

Comment: 'n' is the index of the monitor

Comment: thanks .. MuGik. I will re-arrange my question. I need to find size of current monitor in use.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by the current screen. If it is the screen where the mouse cursor is, you can get the device with:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getDevice();
```

On the other hand, if you need the device where a window is located, use:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
```

From these you can obtain the dimensions:

```
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment, you may obtain all available monitors:

```
GraphicsDevice.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()
```

and know them resolutions

Comment: thanks... cybersoft.. I need the current device and not default device. how do i find it.

Comment: I think it is not possible to know on which device are located your application.

Comment: You can also look at this example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen dimensions using `Toolkit` as follows:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

For multi-screen try following:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```