# How do I use java interop to get screen size in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

**How do I get screen size in Clojure?**

I'm having trouble using Java interop. A demonstration of

```
Toolkit.getScreenSize()
```

would be most useful to me.

I've tried

```
(.getScreenSize Toolkit)
```

after importing the appropriate library and similar stuff but to no avail.

Comment: You can get the screen size the same way you would in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying variations of:

```
(.getScreenSize Toolkit)
```

and

```
(.getScreenSize (.getDefaultToolkit Toolkit))
```

It has to be:

```
(.getScreenSize (Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit))
```

Also for stackers that have no clue you need:

```
(import java.awt.Toolkit)
```

Comment: There's also the `..` form, which can be pretty nice for long chains of `a.b().c()` type things when you're in Java-land. For example `(.. Toolkit getDefaultToolkit getScreenSize)`