# Get current display size in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to get the resolution for the screen the window is currently located in. So if I drag the window from one display to another with a different resolution the application should be able to change.

I'm running this on a thinkpad running ubuntu gnome connected to a external screen.

Here're my current attempts:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class sizetest {

   void run() {
      Display display = new Display();
      Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      shell.setText("sizetest");
      shell.pack();
      shell.open();

      while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
         DisplayMode mode = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
         System.out.println(String.format("Current environment screensize: %s, %s", mode.getWidth(), mode.getHeight()));
         Dimension current = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
         System.out.println(String.format("Current toolkit screensize: %s, %s", current.getWidth(), current.getHeight()));
         Rectangle bounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
         System.out.println(String.format("Bounds %s, %s", bounds.width, bounds.height));
         if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
         }
      }
      display.dispose();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      sizetest o = new sizetest();
      o.run();
   }
}
```

Output is

```
Current environment screensize: 1920, 1080
Current toolkit screensize: 3840.0, 3240.0 
Bounds 1920, 1080
```

Neither of them change when I move the window from one screen to the other.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Added third method from the answer by jan, that too didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how you old Abel to do it directly with SWT, but you could check to see if anynofnthe given GraphicsDevices's contains the window (by comparing bounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an AWT/Swing window, you can query its `GraphicsConfiguration` to get what you want. Note that the different parts of the window can be located on several displays at a time. This method returns the display where the the window center is located. Here's simple component which displays the size of its current display:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Resolution tracker");
        setSize(300, 50);
        add(label);
        updateResolution();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                updateResolution();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void updateResolution() {
        DisplayMode mode = this.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDisplayMode();
        label.setText(mode.getWidth()+" x "+mode.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't use the default graphics config, that was the problem. Thanks.