# Processing find width and height of screen

Tags: java, height, width, screen, processing

I'm trying to make a game in Processing, however I don't want it to be in fixed coordinates. I'd like to make it the height of the screen and the width of the screen divided by 3.
I've tried `screen.width` and `screen.height` but they don't work.

Comment: If you are referring to screen resolution, rather than window size this question should provide your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` they will be holding those data. Here their javaDoc:

http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#displayWidth

Also there is `pixelDensity()` if you want to deal with retina display.

https://processing.org/reference/pixelDensity_.html

`screen.width` and `screen.Height` have been removed

https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes#user-content-changed-and-removed

Comment: This has yet again been replaced by [`pixelWidth`](https://processing.org/reference/pixelWidth.html) and [`pixelHeight`](https://processing.org/reference/pixelHeight.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain your screen size by using Toolkit.getScreenSize() method.

Answer (score -1):

Also if you want you could use the fullScreen() command then use this:

```
    fullScreen();
    if(mouseButton == LEFT){
        println(mouseX + " : " + mouseY);
    }
```

This will print the mouse coordinates when you left click. So click in the bottom right and it will display the X and Y coordinates. Then use a calculator to divide the y by 3.