# Maximum width and maximum height of a screen's device in Processing language?

Tags: java, processing

I am aware that Processing uses variables such as `width` and `height` for getting the width and height of a frame. How about if I want to get the maximum width and maximum height of a device in Processing language (specifically in Java mode)?

The maximum height and maximum width of the device I am using such as a laptop or a smartphone or even a tablet.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` hold the dimensions of the currently active display. If you use `fullScreen()`, `width` and `height` hold the dimensions too.

Comment: Thanks @ciaron, it worked. I am trying to UpVote your answer but, it says I need to increase my reputation in order to vote. I joined recently.

Comment: Hello @ciaron I was just wondering how can I improve when searching for something? I tried looking in the Processing website API but still haven't been successful. Tried searching for    displayWidth     in the Processing website but it didn't return anything.  How can I improve when searching for something or how did you come across those variables?

Comment: This looks to be undocumented (I couldn't find it in the API either), but I had been digging around in the PApplet source when I found it. (https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fprocessing%2Fcore%2FPApplet.java)

Comment: Alternatively you can use [Java directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java/3680236#3680236), because [Processing does the same internally](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fprocessing%2Fcore%2FPApplet.java#L946-L958).

Comment: Thank you too @Darius M.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that [`displayWidth` and `displayHeight` are deprecated as of Processing 3](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0).

Those variables are still available for now though, and [here](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#displayWidth) they are in the API. The problem is that there isn't a guarantee that these variables will be there for much longer.

This means that there isn't a "pure Processing" way to get the dimensions of the display. You'll have to implement a different solution for each deployment target you're using.

- [Here's how to do it using Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-size-in-java/3680236#3680236)
- [Here's how to do it using JavaScript. (Processing.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)
- [Here's how to do it using Android. (Processing Android Mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)