# How can I get monitor width/height using java code?

Tags: java, graphics, monitor

Is it possible to get the width and height of my monitor using some java code?

Comment: Might be this discussion will be help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-screen-resolution-in-java

Answer (score 0):

you can use awt toolkit.

references:

[How can I get screen resolution in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-screen-resolution-in-java)

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-determine-get-screen-size-java-swing-app

Comment: This should be comment not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.awt.Toolkit

Once you have the screen size as a Java Dimension object, you can get the height and width as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // java - get screen size using the Toolkit class
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        //the screen height
        screenSize.getHeight();

        //the screen width
        screenSize.getWidth();

        System.out.println("screenSize==>>"+screenSize);
        System.out.println("Height ==>>"+screenSize.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Widht ===>> "+screenSize.getWidth());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the toolkit you get the resolution in pixels

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```