# Is there a way to get native screen resolution on java?

Tags: java, screen-resolution

I need the resolution of my screen for my project.

I have already tried the Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() function but it does not returns the native resolution because of the Windows's auto scale.
My screen resolution is 1920x1080 but it only returns 1536x864.

```
screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
//it returns 1536x864
```

Comment: It looks like this has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-screen-resolution-in-java

Comment: thanks 
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight(); is solved my problem