# How do I get the dimensions of each individual screen in Java

Tags: java, screen, resolution, monitor

I need a function that gives me the resolutions of my individual monitors.

I do know that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` gives me the cumulative resolution of all monitors, but to limit the size of some frames I draw I want to know the resolutions of the individual screens.

I tried using `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()` which returns an array of all screens, but I could not find any resolution information in there.

The header of the function should be something like

```
/**
 * Returns the Dimension of all available screen devices in order of appearance in  
 * GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()
 * 
 * @return the Dimensions of all available screen devices.
 */
public Dimension[] getScreenResolutions() {
    [ . . . ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this?  The most common reasons for wanting the screen bounds are usually cases that are properly handled by other methods.  To center a window, use setLocationRelativeTo(null).  To fill a screen, use Frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) or GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow.

Comment: First I need to read in an image file, scale it down if it is too big and calculate the size of the frames. Window state is supposed to be non-maximized (the frame fills ~80% of the screen), so for this specific case it now works as intended.

Comment: Centering is done later, when the frame size is already calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the same, while Rob Spoor answered, so I'm gonna give a full answer to my question:

`GraphicsDevice` has a function `getDefaultConfiguration()` which returns a `GraphicsConfiguration` which has a `getBounds()` method which again returns the values as a `Rectangle`.

An implementation of my function header would therefore be:

```
/**
 * Returns the Dimension of all available screen devices in order of appearance in  
 * GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()
 * 
 * @return the Dimensions of all available screen devices.
 */
public Dimension[] getScreenResolutions() {
    // step 1: get amount of screens and allocate space
    int deviceAmount = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices().length;
    Dimension[] dimensions = new Dimension[deviceAmount];
    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[deviceAmount];
    // step 2: get values as Rectangle[]
    for (int i = 0; i < deviceAmount; i++) { 
        rectangles[i] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[i].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    }
    // step 3: convert to Dimension[]
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        dimensions[i] = new Dimension(r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
    }
    // step 4: return
    return dimensions;
}
```

Comment: You can use a stream for that ;): 
 `Arrays.stream(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()).map(GraphicsDevice::getDefaultConfiguration).map(GraphicsConfiguration::getBounds).map(Rectangle::getSize).toArray(Dimension[]::new)`

Comment: See also this if you use [font scaling on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680221/how-can-i-get-screen-resolution-in-java/70294946#70294946)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [GraphicsConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html). The documentation shows how to get the screen bounds.