# Retina-compatible JLabel Image

Tags: java, retina-display

I have two versions of an image: *logo.png* (265x150) and *logo@2x.png* (530x300).
The second one is the retina-version.

In my Java application I have a **JLabel** on which I'm setting the background to an image like so:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
lblNewLabel.setBounds(9, 6, 265, 150);
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("login_logo.png"));
contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
```

This works fine, but I'm not sure how to display the retina-version properly on my Macbook Pro Retina.
The retina image isn't scaled resulting in an image that is only partially visible.

Comment: So you want to detect if you're running on a computer with a retina display. That's your real question isn't it?

Comment: @RobinGreen No, I need a proper way to display a (retina) image on a retina display.

Comment: A png file for a retina display is fundamentally no different from any other png file. There are only images that are designed for retina displays. So I don't understand what your problem is. Why can't you just change the filename?

Comment: Simply changing the filename won't do the trick. The retina image isn't scaled resulting in an image that is only partially visible.

Comment: Aha! And now, finally, you reveal *what your real problem is*. Wouldn't it have been less effort for everyone involved if you had mentioned that upfront? But this still isn't enough detail. When does this happen? Show the code.

Comment: @RobinGreen What else would you like to know? I'm not sure what other details I could provide

Comment: The actual code. Preferably as much as possible. For example, are you calling `setSize` or using a layout manager? Are you dynamically replacing the image?

Comment: While it's fun to see this back and forth, and a learning experience, no doubt, how about a solution that is a bit more generic?  I have a high resolution display, and would appreciate you not displaying the lesser resolution file on my display just because I run Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431148/swing-and-bitmaps-on-retina-displays

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion would be, first check for retina display, then set the image

```
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor")
```

The above line will return 2.0 on retina displays. On non-retina macs it will returns 1.0 and on all other platforms null

try following code

```
public boolean isRatinaDisplay(){
    boolean isRatina = false;
    if (null != Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor") && Float.parseFloat((String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor")) == 2.0) {
       //The above line will return 2.0 on retina displays. 
       //On non-retina macs it will returns 1.0 and on all other platforms null
       isRatina = true;
    }
}
JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("");
if(isRatinaDisplay()){ //if mac set ratina image
  lblLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo@2x.png"));
  lblLabel.setSize(new Dimension(530,300));
  lblLabel.setBounds(9, 6, 530,300);
}else{ //else normal
  lblLabel.setSize(new Dimension(265, 150));
  lblLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo.png"));
  lblLabel.setBounds(9, 6, 265, 150);
}
```

Comment: The mac that I'm using to write this lines doesn't have a retina display ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the method, but simply setting the icon to a larger image won't do the trick. The image is not scaled by Java so only half of it is visible.

Comment: set other properties to scale the image, it will work

Comment: Change dimension of label as per resolution

Comment: updated the code try this, I have not tested this code besause I don't have Mac with retina display

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you are using two images in different sizes/resolutions. A small one for a display with small resolutions and a bigger one for displays with higher resolution.

A retina display differs from other display essentially in its higher resolution.

So you could try to find out the display resolution and check it that matches to the retina display. There are several possibilities to do that. One could be this:
[How do you get the screen width in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936566/how-do-you-get-the-screen-width-in-java)

But maybe it would be better to use the size of your JFrame, since that can be in fullscreenmode, or smaller, and the user can change that, as long as you allow that.
The size of your JFrame can be determined by this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize()

Another thought: In near future there will be more companies then just apple that provide displays in that solution.

Greetings!

Comment: This wasn't my question; I know very well what a retina display is. The point is: I need to properly display the high-res image (retina version!) in my JLabel component.

Comment: @Jeffrey You seem to have the attitude that we are all missing the point. I think the reverse is true. I think you need to slow down, take a deep breath, and read what we are saying more carefully.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Could you explain what exactly a retina-version of a png is? I think this is what I am missing...

Comment: @Jeffrey: What do you mean by "propery display"?

Comment: Ah, sorry... I if I understand it correctly now, you could try to call doLayout() on the Container that is the parent of the JLabel. That should relayout the Container and all it's children, so that the size of the children will be recalculated. But this would only make sense if you change the image after the initial creation of the dialog...

Comment: If you don't change the Image after the initial creation of the dialog. you might have a problem with the layoutmanager. Maybe the LayoutManager doesn't allow the Label to grow.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The image is bigger (in terms of width and height in *pixels*, not in inches) so the JLabel needs to be made bigger (setBounds takes arguments that are measured in *pixels*, not in inches. This is not actually documented in the Javadocs but it is obvious when you check the Javadocs for `setSize`).</strike>

Java "pixels" aren't real pixels on Apple retina displays. See [Swing and bitmaps on retina displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431148/swing-and-bitmaps-on-retina-displays)

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181079/apple-retina-display-support-in-java-jdk-1-7-for-awt-swing) only certain versions of Java support retina displays. I don't know if that's relevant to your problem.

Comment: When properly displayed, the size in inches is indeed the same, but it's not properly displayed so it's still twice the size (in both pixels and inches). As far as I can tell ``setSize`` takes pixels as arguments.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181079/apple-retina-display-support-in-java-jdk-1-7-for-awt-swing) only certain versions of Java support retina displays. I don't know if that's relevant to your problem.

Comment: Other components such as JLabel are displaying fine, so the Java version is not the issue here.